# Computer has locked up, will it recover?

Tags: freeze, lock

I have set some programs to run on my desktop (intensive) and I think they are using all available RAM, to the point that now the machine is completely locked up the clock isn't even updating (it's been 30 mins now). My programs take ~10 hours to run (intense simulations), my question is, if all the RAM is being used up I suspect the programs are having to context switch alot and save to disk to share the RAM, if I just leave the system will it recover? i.e. are the programs still running or is it a complete gonner and I'm just going to have to hard restart?

I've tried ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+t to try and get a terminal up but have had no luck

I've been moving the mouse, I see a few jitters, what worries me is the time has just not updated :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it probably won't recover and you should power cycle it...